# Client Side File Generation and Download

Tags: jquery

Hi as u understand from question title, I want client side file generation and download. I know there is Downloadify that exactly do what I said. But downloadify is using flash + javascript. I just want to do that with jQuery. I have a text and I have a link. When user click the link, it will generate a file with that text and ask user to download it.

Best Regards.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/4551467#4551467)

Comment: Use php or asp instead. Html 5 is not supported by all browsers. Avoiding flash is good though.

Comment: Depends on your usage. IE7 and lower don't support it but IE8 supports data URIs under 32kb while most other browsers support them. If you don't care about the older browsers then it should be fine.

Comment: Hi David, I tried that what u suggest me. But it downloads the data as a .part file how can i set the filetype? Actually i want something excatly like this http://vcardmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this cannot be done with javascript only. That's the reason why Downloadify uses Flash. Another possibility is to generate the file on the server and then point your link to the server side script that will serve the file and the user will be able to download it.